# Error when I try to access Term Stores: Access is denied

Tags: taxonomy, access-denied, term-store, client-object-model

I'm trying to access term stores using CSOM. In Sharepoint log, i found this error message:

> Exception occured in scope
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TermStore.get_Groups.
>   Exception=System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.

NOTE 1: In test server this is working correctly.

NOTE 2: My permissions on metadata service are the same at the two servers.

Anyone have suggestions about the solution of this issue or where I need to check other configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was discovered that the port used for the service of Managed Meta Data was already being used by Project Server and this was causing the access issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got similar exceptions in farm solutions. Normally error was in one of the following setting:

- TermStore was changed by admin or there were several TermStores in productive server, so there was a problem getting the right TermStore object
- Current state of did not send right permissions
- If you are trying to edit TermStore remote: Be sure all former editing requests are completed before doing next edit request
- Easiest and most common one: used user just did not had rights to read the TermStore in productive system and devs used admin account in there test machines ;)

Comment: Thank You! I forgot to say that I'm using CSOM into SharePoint App. Do you have other considerations about this?

Comment: So you are using JavaScript? If this is the case, you could investigate communication with server by tracing connections in your browser or fiddler to find out more. Actually I guess problem will be in configuration of meta store (maybe permission). If you get the answer, I would be happy to hear about the reasons.